# C# TransactionScope - Locking records Issue

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, entity-framework-6

I am using a `TransactionScope` so that i can be sure that either all my data is deleted & saved or everything is rolled back.

But here the issue is that my records are more & it is taking too much time to delete records & on the other hand records are getting locked for the other users.

Here is the Code :-

```
using (var scope = new TransactionScope())
{
      using (var ctx = new ApplicationDbContext(schemaName))
      {
         // Delete
         foreach (var item in queries)
         {
             // Delete queries - more than 30 queries - optimized already
             ctx.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(item);                   
         }

         // Bulk Insert
         BulkInsert(ConnectionString, "Entry", "Entry", bulkTOEntry);
         BulkInsert(ConnectionString, "WrongEntry", "WrongEntry", bulkWrongEntry);
      }
      scope.Complete();          
}
```

The `foreach` loop for delete operation takes too much time & causes locks on the records. If I take that code out of the `TransactionScope` then i will have no facility to Roll Back.

What is the way out of this? Is there any other way i can speed up deletes by something like Bulk Deletes?

-- Added

```
DELETE FROM [Entry] 
WHERE CompanyId = 1 
  AND EmployeeId IN (3, 4, 6, 7, 14, 17, 20, 21, 22,....100 more) 
  AND Entry_Date = '2016-12-01' 
  AND Entry_Method = 'I'
```

Employees Ids are different for different Entry_date.

Execution Plan for Query :-

[image]

Comment: Use stored procedures. Unfortunately transactions are only practical for short operations.

Comment: Prepare a temporary table, outside of the transaction, with all the primary key values of the rows to delete, start a transaction and issue 1 delete statement that deletes them all. However, if the statements you're executing are all against different tables and whatnot this may not be possible.

Comment: When you say "too much time", what **exactly** do you mean? Are we talking milliseconds? seconds? minutes? hours? And "more than 30", how many in a given scenario? 35? 350? 3500? 3.5 million?

Comment: @buffjape That is a wrong and very bad advice. "Short operations" is when no user interaction is involved while the transaction is active. Other than that using a transaction is the correct way, and it does not matter whether or not it is inside a stored procedure.

Comment: @buffjape how stored procedure can be faster -if they will do exactly same job?

Comment: Why you deleting items one by one? Can you run deleting in one query?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen It takes around 10 minutes for delete operation & few seconds for the BulkInsert.

Comment: @Fabio my query is such that i cannot manage in one query. I will update my question with delete queris sample.

Comment: @Anup Then follow Lasse V. Karlsen's advice, prepare a temporary table with `Entry_Date` and `EmployeeId`, fill it with all pairs and execute one delete.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Can you Post an Answer with little summary pseudo code, so that i can mark it as Answer.

Comment: Anyone here can do it and to be honest I'd rather not, as you've already said it isn't really feasible to use that solution. But if anyone else wants to do it (even you, that would be 100% OK), go right ahead.

Comment: Could you use a `Parallel.ForEach` and run them concurrently?

Answer (score 1):

`TransactionScope` defaults to `Serializable` level of isolation. This is the most secure level, but also the least concurrent one. You often want to explicitly set a more common isolation level:

```
using (var scope = new TransactionScope(
             TransactionScopeOption.Required,
             new TransactionOptions() { IsolationLevel = IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted  }))
{ 
   ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for Answer, i will try this thing.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have the correct indexes setup?
I would recommend you extract the execution plan for one of your Delete queries and check what costs the most.

And if possible add a index to fix the issue!

Comment: I already have index on EmployeeId & Entry_Date, more over if i delete this queries directly in SQL Server, it also takes time there. The problem here is Locking & Rolling Back.

Comment: @Anup yes i understand that the query takes time no matter where you execute it, but with some luck you can make it run faster by looking at the execution plan and figure out what makes it so slow..

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, i just managed to run my 1 delete query & have attached an image of execution plan, Please guide me, as i am not aware of Indexes much.!

Comment: @Anup If you right click the execution plan and click on `Missing index details...` this will give you a index that will lower the cost/time with about 95% but it will make updates and inserts slower and take more disk space!